# from XMLHttpRequest set the responseText as the web page

Tags: javascript, html, http-headers, xmlhttprequest

This is the problem I’m trying to accomplish. From a web page I want to create a XMLHttpRequest, set some header values, and get the content of a new web page.  This al works.  But now I have the responseText which is a full web page with JavaScript, and I want to set this page as the content of the current page.

Is this possible?  Can I do something similar another way?  The main constraint I have is that need to use header values and I can’t use URL parameter values.

Thanks

Edit:

Here is my situation; I need to communicate with a 3 party vendor to show their website from my web site.  They only inspect header values, so I need to add an identifier to the header so that they can pick it up and show the correct page.  Their page is a full HTML page with JavaScript.  This is what I was thinking of using:

```
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open("GET", "www.thirdpartydomain.com/specialpage.html", false);
req.setRequestHeader('Special-Identifier','My-Special-Indetifer');
request.send(null);

//request.responseText now contains a whole valid web page that i want to show in the same web browser
```

But how do I get the returned content to replace the current content of my browser?

Comment: Are you trying to fetch a page from a different domain? You can't do this because the receiving domain needs to set the right `CORS` options.

Comment: how are you doing the XMLHttpRequest?

Comment: If you are replacing the entire page, why are you using Ajax at all?

Comment: @Quentin - I don't need to use Ajax but see my edit, as I do need to use header values and not URL parameter values.  Have any ideas?  Thanks

Comment: @Frits van Campen - Yes it is comming from another domain and I am not  what CORS options are.  I never came across them.